# Is it OK to operate with seconds produced by NSDate timeIntervalSince1970?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

Since NSDate represents "a single point in time, independent of any particular calendrical system or time zone", is it OK to make direct calculations with seconds given by its methods like `timeIntervalSince1970`?

I mean operations like add and subtract of two `NSTimeInterval` (aka `double`) values rather than using `dateByAddingTimeInterval:` or `NSCalendar` method like `- (nullable NSDate *)dateByAddingComponents:(NSDateComponents *)comps toDate:(NSDate *)date options:(NSCalendarOptions)opts`.

What issues would have such direct calculations?

Comment: It may be better to use `NSDateComponents`, in most of the case, because for instance, since there are day saving lights, if today's it's 2PM, tomorrow at 2PM may not be in 24h, but 23 or 25.

Comment: Without seeing any specific examples of what you have in mind, it is always best to use `dateByAddingComponents`. But there may be cases where working directly using seconds is OK. But without knowing what you really want to do, the only safe recommendation is to use `dateByAddingComponents`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding may make less sense, but subtracting does make sense if you want to find the difference in time between two dates.

What you want to note, however, is that you should only go for the seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks difference from your subtraction

But to find the difference in months and years, you will want to use the `NSDate` API.  Months and years are not constant

Likewise with adding dates, if you want to add seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks.  Those are constant and easy to add.  But Months and Years will trip you up

Comment: Once a year a day has 23 or 25 hours. Every now and then there is a leap second. Minutes, hours, days and weeks are NOT constant.

Comment: Are you saying it's possible that if you had an NSDate for `now`, and 24 hours in the future, then subtracted the two, you could end up with a number greater than 24*60*60*1000 if a leap second snuck in?  I'm not sure how they wouldn't be constant?

Comment: I don't know about the leap second but I'm sure about the 23 and 25 hours.